# Gracefully close Tornado streaming request

Tags: python, tornado

I have a Tornado `RequestHandler` with the `@tornado.web.stream_request_body` decorator to allow chunked streaming to the handler.

I need to perform authentication and some other checks before allowing streaming. I tried to implement these in the `RequestHandler.prepare()` method, but when I use `requests` to stream data to the handler, and the checks fails, the connection is abruptly closed and I see an exception:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

My `prepare()` method looks like:

```
def prepare(self):
    check = some_function()
    if not check:
        self.set_status(400)
        self.write('some error message')
        self.finish()
        return
```

How can I make sure the request is gracefully closed so I can return an error message to the client if the checks fail?

Comment: You can try to wrap `prepare` with `@coroutine`, that will make Tornado to wait for you to finish checking. Thus, `some_function` also needs to be a coroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to handle this gracefully in HTTP/1. Most clients simply write the request blindly and don't look for a response from the server until they've written the full request, so the only way you can stop them from sending the whole thing is to abruptly shut down the connection.

The behavior you want is found in an obscure HTTP feature called `100-continue`. If the *client* supports this, then it will wait for `prepare()` to finish to see if there is an error before uploading the request. `requests` does not support this feature. Tornado's default HTTP client does, if you pass `expect_100_continue=True` on the fetch.